# I have a child table that depends on two parent tables that are not related. i want to insert rows into child table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

I am creating a database for selling houses.

I have a parent table that I am calling `location` that has three columns :

- locationLat : the latitude of  location of property
- locationLong : the longitude of the property
- locationName : an alternative name that i can use to identify the location of the property by name

Both `locationLat` and `locationlong` make up a composite primary key of this table.

Then I have a child table called `houseToLet`, this table only stores the houses that are for letting. I have similar different tables `houseToBuy`, `fullyFurnished`, `landtoSell` etc. The table for `houseTolet` has a composite primary key like the location table above i.e `locationLat`, `locationLong` and a foreign composite key `location_locationLat` and `location_locationLong` that references the location table.

Then I have another table called  `generalFeatures`. This the table where I store general features of all the properties I am selling. So `generalFeatures table` is a child table of `houseTolet` and `Housetobuy` as well as `Fullyfurnished` tables,

When I insert rows into the `location` table, I find no problem as it is the parent table. When i insert rows into `houseTolet` table I find no problem since it is a child table and I will have inserted the parent location table already. However when I insert into the `generalFeatures` table I get into problem since it is a child table of `housetoBuy` as well as other tables including `Fullyfurnished`.

Please assist me to know how I can do this.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foreign`.`location` (
  `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationName` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLat`, `locationLong`))
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location`.`housetolet` (
  `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('gatedCommunity', 'standalone', 'apartment') NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLat`, `locationLong`),
  INDEX `fk_housetolet_location_idx` (`location_locationLat` ASC, `location_locationLong` ASC))


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foreign`.`generalfeatures` (
  `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `livingAreaAndSize` INT NOT NULL,
  `bedrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `bathrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `masterEnsuite` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `bedroomsWithBathrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `kitchenAndSize` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `parkingAndSlots` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `swimmingPool` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `liftsAndNumber` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `CCTV` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `sizeOfLand` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `borehole` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `housetobuy_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `housetobuy_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `housetolet_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `housetolet_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `fullyfurnished_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `fullyfurnished_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLat`, `locationLong`),
  INDEX `fk_generalfeatures_housetobuy1_idx` (`housetobuy_locationLat` ASC, `housetobuy_locationLong` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_generalfeatures_housetolet1_idx` (`housetolet_locationLat` ASC, `housetolet_locationLong` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_generalfeatures_fullyfurnished1_idx` (`fullyfurnished_locationLat` ASC, `fullyfurnished_locationLong` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_generalfeatures_housetobuy1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`housetobuy_locationLat` , `housetobuy_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`housetobuy` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_generalfeatures_housetolet1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`housetolet_locationLat` , `housetolet_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`housetolet` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_generalfeatures_fullyfurnished1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fullyfurnished_locationLat` , `fullyfurnished_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`fullyfurnished` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I want to be able to insert rows into `generalFeatures` table for houses to Let without getting foreign key constraints that I need to update other tables like `houseTobuy` or `fullyFurnished` first, this is because in a particular instance I will be updating a particular type of a house only but not many options. A house to let cannot be at the same time be a house to buy in my case.

Comment: Why are there two pairs of longitude and latitude in the house to let table? Can the location of the house to let be different of the location of the parent location? And how do the other house and land tables look like? And can there be more than one house/land to one location than one?

Comment: the pair of the longitude and latitude in the house to let is to assist me to create a composite primary key in this table that i can reference the location table .for the last part of your comment since am using latitude and longitude as the primary keys in the location table, am saying that at one particular time in one geographical location there can only be one type of property i.e either house to sell, house to rent, land to buy etc. see the other part of code in next comment.

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `foreign`.`fullyfurnished` (
  `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLat`, `locationLong`),
  INDEX `fk_fullyfurnished_location1_idx` (`location_locationLat` ASC, `location_locationLong` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_fullyfurnished_location1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_locationLat` , `location_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`location` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)

Comment: CREATE TABLE  `foreign`.`housetobuy` (
  `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('gatedCommunity', 'standalone', 'apartment') NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,

Comment: `indoorfeatures_locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `indoorfeatures_locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLat`, `locationLong`),
  INDEX `fk_housetobuy_location1_idx` (`location_locationLat` ASC, `location_locationLong` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_housetobuy_indoorfeatures1_idx` (`indoorfeatures_locationLat` ASC, `indoorfeatures_locationLong` ASC),

Comment: CONSTRAINT `fk_housetobuy_location1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`location_locationLat` , `location_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`location` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_housetobuy_indoorfeatures1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`indoorfeatures_locationLat` , `indoorfeatures_locationLong`)
    REFERENCES `foreign`.`indoorfeatures` (`locationLat` , `locationLong`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Does a given location may appear in several tables at the same time, like it is in `houseToLet` and `houseToBuy` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your database design has flaws. Namely, you are storing in multiple tables information that could be represented as a single record. As it is, it looks like all tables could be merged into main table `locations` :

- the `house*` tables (`houseToLet`, `houseToBuy`, ...) are just there to store the current *status* of the location (to let, to buy, ...) : this could be represented as an `ENUM` field in the `location` table (or as several boolean columns if more than one status can be enabled at a time)
- the `generalFeatures` table also seems to contain a single record for each location, hence all of its fields could be moved to the `location` table.

Using a single table appears like the right design for your use case (and it sure avoids issues with foreign constraints...).

Other considerations : use an autoincremented integer as primary  key instead of a composite key (for this, you can create a `UNIQUE` constraint).

Here is a sample DDL for your table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foreign`.`location` (

    -- primary key
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

    -- original columns
    `locationLat` DECIMAL(10,8) NOT NULL,
    `locationLong` DECIMAL(11,8) NOT NULL,
    `locationName` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,

    -- house status
    `status` ENUM('toLet', 'houseToBuy', 'fullyFurnished', 'landtoSell') NOT NULL,

    -- columns from `generalfeatures`
    `livingAreaAndSize` INT NOT NULL,
    `bedrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `bathrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `masterEnsuite` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `bedroomsWithBathrooms` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL
    -- other columns from `generalfeatures`...
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```